# Image rotation works in lollipop but not in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, image-rotation, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I want spin a bottle on right swipe. It's working fine in ***lollipop*** but in ***marshmallow*** its not working smoothly. The size of the image 100*100.

Please let me know the error and how can I resolve it.

Following is my code:

```
            GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                    // clearAnimation();
                    int sanctity = 50;
                    //
                    Speed = Math.round(velocityX / 1000);
                    if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sanctity) {
                        swipeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        scroller.fling(0, 0, (int) Math.hypot(velocityX, velocityY), 0, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, 0);
                        invalidate();


                    }


                    return true;
                }
            };


            @Override
            public void computeScroll() {
                if (scroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
                    firstime = false;
                    float current = scroller.getCurrX();
                    Log.d("computeScroll ", String.valueOf(current));

                    setRotation(current * FACTOR);

                    invalidate();




                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Button buttonClick;
    ImageView img;
    Bitmap source;
    float angle=0;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
       img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
       // Create Bitmap object for the source image
       source=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Rose.jpg");

       img.setImageBitmap(source);
       buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
       buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View view){
              angle+=90;
              Bitmap rotatedImage=rotateImage(source,angle);
              img.setImageBitmap(rotatedImage);
          }
       });


    }

    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap sourceImage, float angle)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

}
```

Now you just have to create a image view and and button to trigger the rotation event.This is working good in both versions